# Check for updates in Google Contacts data via API

Tags: php, google-api, google-people-api

I'm working on a web program (with PHP) that uses data from Google Contacts (via `People API`, but I'm willing to switch to a different API if this is what it takes). The problem is that getting lots of data from google every time is slow.

To speed things up I want to cache the data in my database, but I still need to make sure the information is **always** up to date.

In Google Calendar I can use [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push) for this purpose, but as far as I know there is no such thing in any of Google Contacts' APIs.

Is there a way to quickly check if any changes were made without requesting the data of all the contacts?

You don't have to write code, just point me in the right direction :)

## What I know so far

I can check if the contact's `etag` matches the cached `etag` to find out whether the contact was edited since it was last cached, but it still requires requesting some of the data of all the contacts to compare the `etag`s, so I end up reducing the traffic by not requesting ALL the data until I know I need it, but it's still more network traffic than I would like.